# Unable to download video only file using ytdl-core chooseFormat options in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ytdl

I am trying to download the youtube video using `Node.js` and `ytdl-core` package. I followed the documentation of `ytdl-core`.

```
ytdl('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aqz-KE-bpKQ')
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('video.mp4'));
```

This works fine but if you want to download the video in high quality you must download download and audio files separately and merge them using ffmpeg. I am unable to download video only using custom function with "**choosing a video format**".

I have an endpoint with `/download` that execute `download()` function in `controller`. This function executes two following functions, `getVideoInfo()` and `downloadVideo()`.

`getVideoInfo()` should create `getInfo.json` and `videoFormat.json` files in `/public` directory.
`downloadVideo()` should download the video file in `/public` directory.

It creates the files successfully but it downloads the video file with 0 bytes.

```
const fs = require("fs")
const path = require("path")
const ytdl = require("ytdl-core")
const cmd = require("node-cmd")
const axios = require("axios")

async function download(req, res) {
  const url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qdi_yp9FA-I"
  const videoPath = "public/video_only.mp4"

  try {
    const videoFormat = await getVideoInfo(url)
    await downloadVideo(url, videoFormat, videoPath)

    console.log('Video is downloaded.')
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error in download function:", error);
    res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
  }
}

async function getVideoInfo(url) {
  const info = await ytdl.getInfo(url)
  console.log("Title: " + info.videoDetails.title)

  // Save info to a JSON file
  fs.writeFileSync("public/getInfo.json", JSON.stringify(info, null, 2))

  const videoFormat = ytdl.chooseFormat(info.formats, { quality: "137" })

  // Save videoFormat to a JSON file
  fs.writeFileSync("public/videoFormat.json", JSON.stringify(videoFormat, null, 2))

  return videoFormat
}

async function downloadVideo(url, videoFormat, videoPath) {
  try {
      if (!videoFormat) {
        reject(new Error("No suitable format found."))
        return
      }

      ytdl(url, { format: videoFormat }).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(videoPath))
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error("Error downloading video: " + error.message)
  }
}

module.exports = {
  download,
}
```

Comment: If you do console.log(videoFormat) it throws and error, it says the itag you specified doesn't exist for the video. For const videoFormat, replace quality: "137" with "higestvideo" or a different itag (134 or 136) and see if it works.

Comment: I just changed the url, where itag: 137 exist. If you open the url from `videoFormat.json` it will play the video on browser.

Comment: But does the video get downloaded successfully?

Comment: No, I just get a file created of 0 bytes in size.

Comment: I actually have a YT downloader made. My code is different from yours since I wrote it in TypeScript, but I hope it helps. The download part is on line 182. The function is saveVideoInDirectory. I added a setTimeout on my function and it somehow helped with some issues. Please let me know if this is of any use to you: https://github.com/divishram/Youtube-downloader/blob/main/backend/src/utils/validURL.ts